# Tab Bar In Split View Controller Master View

Tags: layout, ipad

Currently I am using a `UITabBarController` in my iPad application in the master view of a `UISplitViewController`. However, in my detail view, there is a `UIToolbar`, and the `UITabBar` looks out of place. Is there any alternative?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try asking on stackoverflow.com -- you might get better answers there because of the larger technical userbase. This site is mostly used for discussing UX and interaction design.

Comment: I'm protecting this question because iOS developers keep coming to ask about how you got the "tabbar in the  master view." If someone wants to know how to do that, they should ask [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... are you talking about the top or the bottom tab bars in the detailed view?

With the top I would consider removing the "edit" button in the master view. 
If you find another way to offer that functionality (which I assume is multi-delete and rearrange), then the top bar might look as "one" unit.
But you'll have to mock it up - not sure it'll look good.

The bottom bar bothers me personally a bit more... I'm gonna ask the same question again - do you really need it? Will you just have one command there? What does "home" do anyway? Or is it just a place holder?

Comment: I agree here,  as a user I would think the edit button in the master view and the detail view have the same purpose.  If you want a 'Delete' type action on the master view, I'd use the inline command glyphs on the tabel cells (sorry, can't remember their official name right off)

Comment: I need the home button for my current design - it brings up a summary screen that also shows at the beginning. I'll wait to see if I get any other suggestions.

Comment: Hmmm... if it brings up a summary screen, why is it inside the detailed view? Sounds like it's more suited to the master view...

Answer (score 1):

Tab Bars don't behave nice in a split view. But i've done the inverse with great success. A split view for each tab. You can see screenshots of my implementation at [TexLege.com](http://www.TexLege.com)

For me, the tab bar is the root, and the split views switch out to contain the primary features of the app...

Comment: Just to add on, NavigatorKit on GitHub has an example to do what you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with the other comments - I don't like the 2 edit buttons or the tab bar at the bottom. Having designed a similar UI recently, I ended up changing the tab bar for a toolbar and putting a segmented control inside it.